# Why box-shadow doesn't work fine with position:relative?

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend

I tried to make box-shadow under every row in my table. In chrome, mozilla everything works fine, but not in Internet Explorer 11.

I noticed that in Internet Explorer under row there is color of thead's color and there is a bigger container which cover my shadow. [Internet Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFbkT.png) [Chrome, mozilla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAkya.png)
I tried use pseudo element `::after` but when I used it I can't click on row, select text etc.

I noticed too if I change position to `absolute` width of row is smaller but box shadow works fine.

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 3px;
  padding: 0 2px;

  &-row {
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    border: 1px solid $c-white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: $c-white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 7px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
     }
}
```

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="table-header-cell">
      <mat-checkbox
        [hidden]="hideSelectAllCheckbox"
        color="primary"
        (change)="$event ? toggleSelectAll() : null; onSelectionChange()"
        [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
        [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
      >
      </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="table-cell button">
      <mat-checkbox
        color="primary"
        [disabled]="dataSource[getRowIndex(row)].options.disabled"
        (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
        (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null; onSelectionChange()"
        [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
      >
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Is any solution to make `::after` clickable or make  transparent the div under row ?

Comment: Can u plz send me the full code?

Comment: It will be hard, because there are many code in my project.

Comment: ok.. but i need little bit structure.. like <table><div class="row"></div></table>

Comment: jyst set a minimum of code that reproduce and shows your issue. from what you show us, an HTML table or div turned into table via display should work with no difference that position is toggled from static to relative.

Comment: @Manikandan2811 could be something alike : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xvPyoY but it doesn't show any trouble :(

Comment: Your problem might be here `&-row`, it should be `&.row`

Comment: @Enve , it generates the class .table-row , unless it is missing on the HTML side, this not an issue as far as we can guess here ;) https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xvPyoY

Comment: Every think works fine on chrome, mozilla, opera but I have problem in Internet Explorer. As you can see on images I uploaded there is no transparent background, and this is my problem.